# How to store user-defined function in GDB?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

After i quit GDB every user-defined function disappear. Im sure there should be some way to make it available between sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB reads the following [files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html) before starting: `~/.config/gdb/gdbinit`, `~/.gdbinit`.

It is a common practice to edit e.g. `~/.gdbinit` to define the user-defined function using an external editor and use `source ~/.gdbinit` in a GDB session to reload that file. Once the function works as you expect, just leave it in your `~/.gdbinit` and it will be available in all future GDB sessions.